# Linker error just after start using parse.com's PFLogInViewController and PFSignUpViewController in iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, storyboard, pfloginviewcontroller

Hi I have added parse into my iOS project and am trying to use PFLogInViewcontroller and PFSignUpViewController. I added all required libraries and specifically social.framework and accounts.framework too

but I am  getting 6 errors after initializing "PFLogInViewController" and "PFSignUpViewController" the code I wrote is as below :

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
[logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

// Create the sign up view controller
PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
[signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

// Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
[logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

// Present the log in view controller
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

If I remove these lines, then the build is successful, can any one guide me what and where I'm missing, the below are the errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)

"_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter setAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)

```
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can I use PFLogInViewController using storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with cocoapods. It's work for me :)

**Edited**

If you don't like installing with cocoapods, just add "Account.framework" and "Social.framework" in Build phases / Link Binary with libraries.

[image]